# Access Large Dataset SQLite

Tags: sqlite, dataset

I am trying to open a very large dataset in SQLite. It has no extension. Now I cannot open it in SQLite. How can I do it? What will be the command and where should I place that dataset file?

I searched over the net but couldn't get the appropriate command for the opening and viewing the dataset.

Comment: What you mean with very large? You should quantify large (whats large for one isn't necessarily for another). Also 'can not open' you should explain. Are you getting a error message? Post some of the code and logging.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have datasets, it has databases. Command line tool to operate on databases is [`sqlite3`](http://sqlite.org/download.html), it will open SQLite database even if it does not have an extension, but it must be valid SQLite database, that is, it should have string `SQLite Format 3` as [first bytes in database file](http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html).

In other words, use this:

```
sqlite3 yourdatabase
sqlite> .tables
a b c
sqlite> SELECT * FROM a LIMIT 10
...
```

You can also use numerous SQLite tools and libraries for different programming languages like C/C++, Java, Perl, Python, etc. to access that database.